# Extracting Taylor coefficients of a quotient

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, complex-analysis

I was wondering if anybody has come across functions of the form $$\Phi_n(z):=\frac{f(z)^{n+1}}{zf'(z)-f(z)}\quad (n\geq 1).$$ Here, $$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_kz^k$$ is holomorphic on the open unit disk and $$a_0=1.$$ I am interested in extracting the Taylor coefficients of $$\Phi_n.$$

Comment: Are you willing to share some background?

Comment: Maple code $$f := z-> 1+sum(a[n]*z^n, n = 1 .. infinity):Phi[n] := f(z)^n/(z*(eval(diff(f(x), x), x = z))-f(z)):taylor(Phi[n], z, 5) $$ produces $$-1-n*a[1]*z+(-(1/2)*n^2*a[1]^2+(1/2)*n*a[1]^2-n*a[2]-a[2])*z^2+ $$ $$(-n*a[3]-(1/3)*n*a[1]^3+(1/2)*n^2*a[1]^3-n^2*a[1]*a[2]-(1/6)*n^3*a[1]^3-2*a[3])*z^3+\dots $$ I don't see any general  coefficient formula here.

Comment: Any particular $f(z)$?